# Pandoc CMD call tex template and pass variables

Tags: pdf, pandoc, variable, parameters, command-line

I'm trying to pass variables to a tex template to generate a PDF with those values via pandoc.

This is my template:

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}

% Margins
\topmargin=-0.45in
\evensidemargin=0in
\oddsidemargin=0in
\textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=9.0in
\headsep=0.25in

\newcommand{\Ticket}{}
\newcommand{\Autor}{}
\newcommand{\Erstelldatum}{}

\title{Ticket: \Ticket}
\author{Erstellt von: \Autor}
\date{Erstellt am: \Erstelldatum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I've tried running these commands but somehow the variables are remaining empty:

```
pandoc.exe -o test.pdf -s template.tex --variable Ticket=12345
pandoc.exe -o test.pdf -s template.tex --variable=Ticket=12345
pandoc.exe -o test.pdf -s template.tex --variable=Ticket:12345
```

Comment: Pandoc variables in the tex file should be inside `$`, e.g. `$foo$`.

Answer (score 1):

As @dexteritas already pointed out: Template variables are enclosed in `$`. This is documented in the [manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#template-syntax).

Also you need to load the template with the option `--template=` and you must make sure that you load all the packages `pandoc` actually needs. It is best to get the default template with `pandoc -D latex` and modify it.

Let's call your file `template.latex`:

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}

% Margins
\topmargin=-0.45in
\evensidemargin=0in
\oddsidemargin=0in
\textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=9.0in
\headsep=0.25in


\title{Ticket: $Ticket$}
\author{Erstellt von: $Autor$}
\date{Erstellt am: $Erstelldatum$}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Then call pandoc:

```
pandoc --template=template.latex \
       -V Ticket=12345 \
       -V Autor="Vorname Nachname" \
       -V Erstelldatum=2023-04-20
       --in test.md --out test.pdf
```